# how to change __consumer_offsets cleanup plicy to delete from compact?

Tags: apache-kafka, delete-file

I have kafka clusters with 3 nodes,in kafka log directory have `__consumer_offsets-XX`,lots of log files as 100MB used by disk place over 90%, excutes command:

```
./bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --entity-name __consumer_offsets --entity-type topics
```

Configs for topics:`__consumer_offsets` are:

```
segment.bytes=104857600,cleanup.policy=compact,compression.type=producer
```

This topic cleanup policy is compact,how to change to delete?

Answer (score 2):

This topic is system topic for kafka. Two clean up policies are applied to it: compaction and delete(offsets.retention.minutes).

If you want to decrease size of that topic:

1. change segment.bytes to smaller amount (param offsets.topic.segment.bytes)
2. decrease retention policy for unused consumer groups (param offsets.retention.minutes)
3. try to decrease amount of partitions for this topic (param offsets.topic.num.partitions)

Comment: I found my server.properties set 'log.cleaner.enable=false' by default,then set 'log.cleaner.enable=true' and restart kafka broker when is beginging marked delete and remove logfile.